# Bootstrap 3: make a button group to fill column (with caret button)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My goal is to fill a column with a couple of buttons. The first button has a text and should fill the remaining space in the column. The second is an icon. To be clear, that looks like an HTML select element with 'width: 100% ".

The solution should be responsive.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg">
                Select an Option
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg">
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        Other assets
    </div>
</div>
```

**PLUNKER**

http://plnkr.co/edit/NezDJL?p=preview

Comment: Something like 'http://embed.plnkr.co/5nDY9VIr6zTfu4PIHClZ/preview' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I would do:

Instead of playing with percentages, I would give full 100% to the first button.
Then I would use the override the style of the "caret" button to absolute, and position it to the top right corner of the parent div (.btn-group).
It will overlap the button and give the desired result

http://plnkr.co/edit/Li2j9Q?p=preview

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg" style="width:100%;">
                Select an Option
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg" style="position:absolute;top:0;right:0;">
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        Other assets
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

Without custom CSS, bootstrap uses a [block](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-sizes) level button:

> those that span the full width of a parent— by adding .btn-block.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Block level button<span class="caret pull-right"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">Other assets</div>
</div>
```

You will have to resize the caret icon though

[BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/r84Msbvi8w)

Comment: This is a much better answer than adding custom CSS inline with HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You could attack it two ways: Utilizing the floats, with percentage widths ( parent too ), adjusting accordingly so it adds up to `100%`

http://embed.plnkr.co/5nDY9VIr6zTfu4PIHClZ/preview

**OR**

You could have the larger button 100% and absolutely position the smaller toggle, but that could be tricky when scaling down.

Comment: Looking at this now .. you could probably just abandon the `:last-child` and have a default `width` and `padding` for the `.button`s in general, and override the first with `:first-child` - http://embed.plnkr.co/owT2QpUlN1udaDekRe9B/preview